OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal not loaded after introspect is executed
I have created a Spring Security 6 project with opaque token configuration implemented in resource server. I already have an authorization server deployed both to test/prod environments.
My introspector is invoked from a custom class below:
@Slf4j
public class CustomAuthoritiesOpaqueTokenIntrospector implements OpaqueTokenIntrospector {
    private OpaqueTokenIntrospector delegate;

    public CustomAuthoritiesOpaqueTokenIntrospector(String oauthServerUrl, String clientId, String clientSecret) {
        this.delegate = new NimbusOpaqueTokenIntrospector(oauthServerUrl, clientId, clientSecret);
    }

    public OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal introspect(String token) {
        OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal principal = this.delegate.introspect(token);
        return new DefaultOAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal(
                principal.getName(), principal.getAttributes(), extractAuthorities(principal));
    }

    private Collection<GrantedAuthority> extractAuthorities(OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal principal) {
        List<String> scopes = principal.getAttribute("scope");
        return scopes.stream()
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

which I copied from this documentation
Here is my resource server config:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ResourceServerConfiguration {
    @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
    private String activeProfile;

    @Value("${root.url.osb.basic.auth}")
    private String osbBasicAuth;

    @Value("${auth.server.url}")
    private String oauthServerUrl;

    @Value("${auth.server.clientId}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${auth.server.clientsecret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    public static final String BEARER_PREFIX = "Bearer ";
    public static final String HEADER_NAME = "Authorization";
    private final UserService userService;

    public ResourceServerConfiguration(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterAfter(new OncePerRequestFilter() {
            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                            HttpServletResponse response,
                                            FilterChain filterChain)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
                // We don't want to allow access to a resource with no token so clear
                // the security context in case it is actually an OAuth2Authentication
                var authHeader = request.getHeader(HEADER_NAME);
                if (StringUtils.isEmpty(authHeader) || !StringUtils.startsWith(authHeader, BEARER_PREFIX)) {
                    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
                }
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        }, AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class);
//        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.requestMatchers("/", "/v1/open/**").permitAll());

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.requestMatchers("/pension/**").authenticated())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());

        if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(activeProfile, "dev")) {
            http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
                authorize.requestMatchers("/webjars/**", "/resources/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/swagger-resources/**", "/v2/api-docs", "index.html")
                .permitAll());
        }

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                        .opaqueToken(Customizer.withDefaults())
                );
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        String[] authParts = osbBasicAuth.split(":");
        String username = authParts[0];
        String password = authParts[1];

        UserDetails userDetails = User.builder()
                .username(username)
                .password(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(password)).roles()
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
    }

    @Bean
    public OpaqueTokenIntrospector introspector() {
        return new CustomAuthoritiesOpaqueTokenIntrospector(oauthServerUrl + "check_token", clientId, clientSecret);
    }
}

For this process, token is fetched from the authorization server, via link http://localhost:9696/oauth/token
which is called separately, in my case via Postman. After I get a token, I call another service by pasting this token to the authorization header.
For example, I call this endpoint: http://localhost:9090/v1/lead-management/get-details/18410 and this endpoint is private and executes only with tokens.
After I execute it, the first thing happens is my introspect is triggered by calling http://localhost:9696/oauth/http://localhost:9696/oauth/check_token in order to validate my token, and then it calls the final endpoint. The token validation is successful, I got all details necessary to prove that my user is authenticated: here
However, the final endpoint throws 500 error. And here I don't have a clue what the problem is about and it seems to me that Principal wasn't mapped or loaded correctly.
I have been dealing with this mess for about 1 month now and still can't seem to find a solution. I hope you can help to solve this problem. Thanks!
-- UPDATE --
Since some of you mentioned about error logs for 500 error, I decided to put logs in here, so you can see that these logs also don't give much information about the source of a problem.
Securing GET /v1/lead-management/get-details/18410
07-11-2024 09:29:55.723 http-nio-9090-exec-1 [correlationId: ] [DEBUG] CompositeLog - HTTP POST http://localhost:9696/oauth/check_token
07-11-2024 09:29:55.732 http-nio-9090-exec-1 [correlationId: ] [DEBUG] InternalLoggerFactory - Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
07-11-2024 09:29:55.734 http-nio-9090-exec-1 [correlationId: ] [DEBUG] CompositeLog - Accept=[text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*] 07-11-2024 09:29:55.734 http-nio-9090-exec-1 [correlationId: ] [DEBUG]  CompositeLog - Writing [{token=[3055687b-6c25-4a59-894e-3a209ce3f1d7]}] with org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter 07-11-2024 09:29:55.748 http-nio-9090-exec-1 [correlationId: ] [DEBUG] LoggingProviderImpl$JULWrapper - sun.net.www.MessageHeader@33d105118 pairs: {POST /oauth/check_token HTTP/1.1: null}{Accept: application/json}{Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8}{Authorization: Basic VVNFUl9DTElFTlRfUlM6dGVzdA==}{User-Agent: Java/17.0.7}{Host: localhost:9696}{Connection: keep-alive}{Content-Length: 42}
07-11-2024 09:29:55.935 http-nio-9090-exec-1 [correlationId: ] [DEBUG] LoggingProviderImpl$JULWrapper -
                    sun.net.www.MessageHeader@4978153910 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 200}{X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff}{X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block}{Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate}{Pragma: no-cache}{Expires: 0}{X-Frame-Options: DENY}{Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8}{Transfer-Encoding: chunked}{Date: Thu, 11 Jul 2024 04:29:55 GMT}
07-11-2024 09:29:55.936 http-nio-9090-exec-1 [correlationId: ] [DEBUG] CompositeLog -
                    Response 200 OK
07-11-2024 09:29:55.937 http-nio-9090-exec-1 [correlationId: ] [DEBUG] CompositeLog -
                    Reading to [java.lang.String] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
07-11-2024 09:29:56.002 http-nio-9090-exec-1 [correlationId: ] [DEBUG] OpaqueTokenAuthenticationProvider -
                    Authenticated token
07-11-2024 09:29:56.002 http-nio-9090-exec-1 [correlationId: ] [DEBUG] BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter -
                    Set SecurityContextHolder to BearerTokenAuthentication [Principal=org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.DefaultOAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal@4879b039, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[role_admin, role_user]]
07-11-2024 09:29:56.006 http-nio-9090-exec-1 [correlationId: ] [DEBUG] FilterChainProxy -
                    Secured GET /v1/lead-management/get-details/18410
07-11-2024 09:29:56.016 http-nio-9090-exec-1 [correlationId: ] [DEBUG] FilterChainProxy -
                    Securing GET /error
07-11-2024 09:29:56.017 http-nio-9090-exec-1 [correlationId: ] [DEBUG] FilterChainProxy -
                    Secured GET /error
07-11-2024 09:29:56.019 http-nio-9090-exec-1 [correlationId: ] [DEBUG] LogFormatUtils -
                    "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
07-11-2024 09:29:56.021 http-nio-9090-exec-1 [correlationId: ] [DEBUG] AbstractHandlerMapping -
                    Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
07-11-2024 09:29:56.022 http-nio-9090-exec-1 [correlationId: ] [DEBUG] OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor -
                    Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
07-11-2024 09:29:56.052 http-nio-9090-exec-1 [correlationId: ] [DEBUG] AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor -
                    Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
07-11-2024 09:29:56.054 http-nio-9090-exec-1 [correlationId: ] [DEBUG] LogFormatUtils -
                    Writing [{timestamp=Thu Jul 11 09:29:56 ORAT 2024, status=500, error=Internal Server Error, path=/v1/lead-man (truncated)...]
07-11-2024 09:29:56.098 http-nio-9090-exec-1 [correlationId: ] [DEBUG] OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor -
                    Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
07-11-2024 09:29:56.099 http-nio-9090-exec-1 [correlationId: ] [DEBUG] FrameworkServlet -
                    Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 500


500 means there are some error logs

And what about the authorization server logs? You set-up a custom introspector which doesn't achieve much (maps authorities from scope claim like the default one and does not log what happens). Maybe should you set some breakpoints there and inspect what happens.

Authorization server logs don't give much info, just some simple debug logs outputted to screen. By the way, for now I launched this auth server locally, because addressing server on test via local resource config gave me PKIX error.
I tried to put breakpoints for introspect, but still I couldn't track any problems. The introspect goes to check_token and validates it successfully, and later just didn't map authorities to my end ouath2 user. However after implementing an approach without a custom class and implementing authorities right to config properties for my surprise solved a problem.

After some tweaks by my teamlead, it finally worked. Using custom introspector class was removed and resource server configuration was modified to this:
http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
    .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
    .opaqueToken(opaqueTokenConfigurer -> opaqueTokenConfigurer
    .introspectionUri(oauthServerUrl + "check_token")
    .introspectionClientCredentials(clientId, clientSecret)
  )
);

OpaqueTokenIntrospector bean was also removed

There are several things that need to be changed.
General considerations
As pointed out in comments by @j-asgarov you shouldn't report a 500 and omit logs.
The only valid case to pay for the inefficiency of introspection was to keep some control over user state ("sessions") when this state was offloaded to the frontend (token sent to single-page or mobile apps). But as this is now discouraged in favor of the OAuth2 BFF pattern, no good reason remains to prefer introspection over JWT decoding.
Broken security conf
You should have one SecurityFilterChain bean per authorization mechanism. Here, you seem to want some requests to be authorized with a Basic auth and others with Bearer auth. You need different filter chains (all with distinct @Order and all but the last one in order with a securityMatcher).
You don't need a specific filter to forbid anonymous requests. authenticated() in each filter chain is enough.
What is the point of permitAll() when you express the requirement that anonymous requests should be prohibited (and that you even create a filter for that)?
What to do next
Unless what consumes your resource server is rendered server-side (Thymeleaf, JSF, etc.), study the OAuth2 BFF pattern.
Switch your resource server(s) from introspection to JWT decoding (and configure the authorization server to serve JWT access tokens if it doesn't yet).
Drop your custom filter (the feature is included in Spring's request authorization and you probably need anonymous access to some resources).
Create distinct security filter-chain beans for Basic and Bearer authorizations.

In my case, I will most likely opt out of switching to JWT decoding, because this authorization server was actually deployed by company employees in the past and my teamlead tells me, that I have to use opaque token for this project.
I temporarily commented out all configs related to basic auth for now and when tried to post a request, it still triggers the same error.
